# Grade book program that works on gentoo

Tags: x11, gentoo

I am looking for a program that I can use to keep track of and calculate my grade in all my classes without going through and making a spreadsheet for each class.

Comment: If you're teaching CS, you could have your students write one as an assignment and use the best one.

Comment: not as a teacher as a student

Comment: Could you be more specific? What's the big deal about spreadsheet? Writing the average formula?

Answer (score 1):

If your school doesn't use any gradebook system you should consider it :)

Google found several linux projects like [GradeL](http://gradel.sourceforge.net/), [GNota](https://launchpad.net/gnota), etc. Try them. Imho "that works on gentoo" is not relevant while you can build almost everything from sources on GNU/linux and especially on Gentoo.

Probably you should consider some platform-independent web application too (google it). You can access your data from another computers (public, friend's), that's a big benefit.

I know you don't want a spreadsheets, but if I were you, I'll create one google docs spreadsheet with couple of sheet tabs.